# Executing user-generated JavaScript from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, django

I am developing a web application in Django. Vital to this application's core functionality is taking user generated JavaScript and submitting it through a form into a MySQL database. This JavaScript code will then be served into webpages that anyone will be able to see, where it performs some calculations behind-the-scenes. I know this is very dangerous because of XSS and perhaps other reasons, but is there any way that I can do this safely? Has anyone ever done this or seen it work successfully?

Also, the most important thing that the JavaScript needs to do is math. Maybe there's a scripting language that doesn't have all of the power of JavaScript that can still run in the browser? Then I could sanitize the input making sure it is that math language and nothing else.

Comment: You could always filter against a white/black list, but that wouldn't guarantee security. My advice is to send submissions to an approval queue if you have the labor available.

Comment: Regarding the edit: it's reasonably easy to make your own scripting language for math. I think most computer science majors have to do that at some point when getting their degree.

Comment: It looks like using a secure subset of JavaScript is what I want to do. I'm looking into google Caja, and I think that's going to work: https://developers.google.com/caja/